# Add a C++ dll in Visual Studio 2012 - No references folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dllimport

Ok, so I've seen a few tutorials tell me how to do this but my interface and results don't match theirs.  I've done this a lot myself with C#, and I don't get why the difference is.

*I have a third party dll (and lib, and .h files)

*I have a project in Visual Studio 2012 Express

*I want to add the dll to the project (I believe what I want is to implicitly link).

There is no References folder in my Solution Explorer.  If I select [Project > Properties > Framework and References > Add New Reference] then all it will show me is other projects in my solution.  I've looked around at the project options (Linker > Additional Dependencies, etc) but there are a lot of possible places which might do something (or not) in who-knows-what combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ and C# are different. when you choose c++ project it requires different approach than C# to configure things. You have to add first you header files path in additional include directory then you dll path in linker and dll name in linker input in project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **.lib** file to the `Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` field, and `#include` the **.h** file. The **.dll** file will need to be in the search path which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx).